# Finding all checkpoints path in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

So far I have used saving and loading checkpoints in Tensorflow only for loading the last checkpoint. Usually the code I use to this is along the lines:

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(load_dir)
if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
else:
    tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(load_dir)
    tf.gfile.MakeDirs(load_dir)
```

However, in my latest experiment, I'm saving a checkpoint at every 1000 iterations and I want to run an evaluation script on all of the checkpoints, e.g. to show how does different validation metrics progress. Is there any easy way of getting all checkpoints in Tensorflow or I will just need to loop over all of the names accordingly using `os`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ckpt` object in your code snippet is [CheckpointState](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_state.proto#L9) protocol buffer. Instead of accessing the most recent model path (`ckpt.model_checkpoint_path`), you can iterate over all of them using something like:

```
for model_path in ckpt.all_model_checkpoint_paths:
    saver.restore(session, model_path)
    # Do the evaluation using the restored model
```

Comment: I guess I can parse the name to find which iteration they are from so I accept this as an answer.